# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC data seeder not populating categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In the code below the `AppUser` and the `Contact` are being created, but the `Category` is not. The error in the terminal is...

> null value in column "AppUserId" of relation "Categories" violates not-null constraint

It is a Postgresql db with a one to many of `AppUser` to `Contact`, and `AppUser` to `Category`. I can create a category in the app ok, and it shows both the `Name` and `AppUser` fields populated correctly, but for some reason the seeder isn't doing that.

This is strange since the `AppUserId` is correctly populated for the contact record. I can't understand why it would not do the same for the `Category` record. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
using ContactPro.Data;
using ContactPro.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ContactPro.Helpers
{
    public class DataSeeder
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

        private static string appUserId;

        public DataSeeder(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task SeedDataAsync()
        {
            await SeedUsersAsync();
            await SeedContactsAsync();
            await SeedCategoriesAsync();
        }

        private async Task SeedUsersAsync()
        {
            if (_dbContext.Users.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var demoUser = new AppUser()
            {
                UserName = "demouser@mail.com",
                Email = "demouser@mail.com",
                FirstName = "Demo",
                LastName = "User",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(demoUser, "xxxxxx");
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            appUserId = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "demouser@mail.com").Id;
        }

        private async Task SeedContactsAsync()
        {
            if (!_dbContext.Contacts.Any())
            {
                var contact = new List<Contact>()
                {
                    new Contact()
                    {
                        FirstName = "John",
                        LastName = "Dickens",
                        Address1 = "12 Main St.",
                        City = "Concord",
                        States  = ContactPro.Enums.States.NH,
                        ZipCode = 03101,
                        Email = "john@mail.com",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                    }
                };

                await _dbContext.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contact);
                await _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private async Task SeedCategoriesAsync()
        {
            if (!_dbContext.Categories.Any())
            {
                var category = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "_UnCategorized",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                    },
                };

                await _dbContext.Categories.AddRangeAsync(category);
                await _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please add the log to the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), and then print the appUserId in the console.

My suggestion is to create a default value for the column or remove the not-null constraint from the column.

```
using ContactPro.Data;
using ContactPro.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ContactPro.Helpers
{
    public class DataSeeder
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

        private static string appUserId;

        public DataSeeder(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<AppUser> userManager,ILogger<DataSeeder> logger)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task SeedDataAsync()
        {
            await SeedUsersAsync();
            await SeedContactsAsync();
            await SeedCategoriesAsync();
        }

        private async Task SeedUsersAsync()
        {
            if (_dbContext.Users.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var demoUser = new AppUser()
            {
                UserName = "demouser@mail.com",
                Email = "demouser@mail.com",
                FirstName = "Demo",
                LastName = "User",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(demoUser, "xxxxxx");
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("****** at {DT}", 
        DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());
            appUserId = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "demouser@mail.com").Id;
            _logger.LogInformation("****** at {DT}", 
        DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());
        }

        private async Task SeedContactsAsync()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("****** at {DT}", 
        DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());

            if (!_dbContext.Contacts.Any())
            {
                var contact = new List<Contact>()
                {
                    new Contact()
                    {
                        FirstName = "John",
                        LastName = "Dickens",
                        Address1 = "12 Main St.",
                        City = "Concord",
                        States  = ContactPro.Enums.States.NH,
                        ZipCode = 03101,
                        Email = "john@mail.com",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                    }
                };
                _logger.LogInformation("****** at {DT}", 
        DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());

                await _dbContext.Contacts.AddRangeAsync(contact);
                await _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private async Task SeedCategoriesAsync()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("****** at {DT}", 
        DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());

            if (!_dbContext.Categories.Any())
            {
                var category = new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        Name = "_UnCategorized",
                        AppUserId = appUserId,
                    },
                };
                _logger.LogInformation("****** at {DT}", 
        DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString());

                await _dbContext.Categories.AddRangeAsync(category);
                await _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```